# Rust library to serialize OWL in Manchester Syntax

Tags: library, knowledge-base, rust

I am writing an RDF browser in Rust based on the [Sophia library](https://crates.io/crates/sophia) which works great for knowledge bases, but ontology descriptions written in OWL are displayed as multiple RDF triples, which is not optimal.

I am thus looking for a Rust library that can serialize small amounts of RDF, preferably parts of a Sophia Graph, into a string in Manchester Syntax.